# Angular Lazy Loading - Is it okay to retain the providers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading

Out of the box Angular does not support deferred script loading.  I have created a solution to this problem, but have a question about the way in which it is done.

In the *exampleModule.config()* below I have replaced the default *module.controller* with the *$controllerProvider.register*.  This allows a reference to the controller provider to be maintained and allows controllers to be registered with the module at a later time (when they are lazy loaded).

While this approach works and I have not experienced any problems to date, I do question whether this is the right thing to do.  **Is it okay to replace the *module.controller* or am I unknowingly breaking Angular in the process?**

```
var module = angular.module("exampleModule", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]);
module.config(function ($provide, $compileProvider, $controllerProvider, $filterProvider, $routeProvider) {

    // Define the routes with their script dependencies
    var routeConfig = { ... omitted for brevity };

    // Retain the angular providers for use when resources are lazily loaded
    module.factory = $provide.factory;
    module.service = $provide.service;
    module.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
    module.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
    module.filter = $filterProvider.register;

    // Add route "dependencies" to the route resolve configuration
    angular.forEach(routeConfig.routes, function (route, path) {
        route.resolve = route.resolve || {};

        // Add a new function to the resolve object.  This function will use require.js
        // to download all the dependent scripts before "resolving" the promise
        route.resolve.requiredDependencies = ["$q", "$rootScope", function ($q, $rootScope) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            require(route.dependencies, function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }];

        $routeProvider.when(path, route);
    });

    // Configure the default route using the route config
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: routeConfig.defaultRoutePath });
});
```

I have seen other examples where the *controllers.register* is retained in another object `module.register.controllers = $controllerProvider.register;` 
But this solution has the added overhead of requiring that every controller that will be lazily loaded be declared in a non-standard way.  In addition these controllers cannot be eagerly loaded since the *module.register* object is not created until the module is configured.  The solution included above solves both these problems.  But at what expense?

Here is a gist with a more complete view of the code.  https://gist.github.com/johngully/9964066

Comment: This is a bit of a philosophical question, rather than technical because as you say you don't have problems with it. As you know yourself problem could come up with a major angular update. If it will keep your mind at peace, you should programmatically check version of angular and break the application if version doesn't match / goes above certain threshold. Other than that, I don't see a problem with your solution because it's fully transparent.

Comment: @nikola-radosavljevic While it is somewhat a philosophical question, I would like to drive to a more technical answer.  Perhaps this phrasing would be better: "Are there any technical problems with this solution that I may be unaware of?"